# A language that is RE complete with respect to polynomial-time reductions?

Tags: computation-theory, reduction, turing-machines

Is there any language in RE that is complete with regard to polynomial-time reductions?

I think that A_TM will be a good example,but I'm not sure...

Comment: Not so hard to find on the web: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_(complexity)#RE-complete

Answer (score 0):

Yes, A<sub>TM</sub> is **RE**-complete with respect to polynomial-time reductions. Given any **RE** language L, let M be a recognizer for it. Then the function f(w) =  can be computed in polynomial time (for some reasonable representation of tuples) because M is a fixed machine and the length of w in the encoded version should certainly be at most polynomially larger than the original input w. We also have that w ∈ L if and only if M accepts w if and only if  ∈ A<sub>TM</sub>, so f is a polynomial-time reduction from an arbitrary **RE** language L to A<sub>TM</sub>, making A<sub>TM</sub> **RE**-complete with respect to polynomial-time reductions.

I'm not sure why you'd be interested in this particular notion of **RE**-completeness, since **RE** is mostly useful for notions of *computability* (can you solve this problem at all?) while polynomial-time reductions are usually for *complexity* (can you solve this problem efficiently?) If you do have an interesting use case for them, though, I'd love to hear about it!